# Recovery from stripped starter threads in engine block

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, starter, stripped-thread, tap

I have a 2004 Honda CRV and slightly stripped the the aluminum block threads as I tightened the new starter down for the top bolt. Now when I try to tighten it, it won't "grab" on to the threads and drive deeper, it just spins. The bolt appears to be in fine condition.

I'm thinking I'll have to retap the hole; however, I believe only the outermost threads are stripped (probably <1/4"), while the threads deeper in the hole are fine. I would like to attempt tapping the hole at the same thread/pitch it's currently set for before moving to the next bigger size, but I want to guarantee that the threads deeper in will line up with my newly recut threads. I know regular taps are tapered a bit, will that be sufficient or do there exist taps specifically for recutting the outside of the hole (i.e. they are extremely tapered and grab onto the threads deeper in and recut only the outer threads as you tighten)? Or is there something else I'm missing? I think it's a M10-1.25.

I'll add it's pretty tight, I couldn't fit my drill in there, but I'm guessing such a drill exists. Also not really room for a full size tap wrench, I'd probably have to replace the handles with short bolts.

Comment: Is there room in the hole, and are the deeper threads in good enough condition, to attempt using a longer bolt?

Comment: Is it a "through" hole? - could you run the tap in from the back?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think it's a through hole, but I'll have to check. Not sure how hard it would be to get at it from the other end, but a good thought.

Comment: @CharlieRB Not sure what you mean. My problem is I can't get the current bolt in more than ~1/8" of an inch, again because the outer threads are damaged.

Comment: I might just try to grind one side of the tap on the end a little bit, try to position it in the hole so it matches the deeper threads, and go from there.

Comment: What I was referring to is a longer bolt may bypass the damaged threads and get a grip on the good threads deeper in the hole.

Comment: I'm not explaining it well. The bolt I have is very long, but I can't get it past the initial stripped threads to the deeper ones, though it is long enough to reach them.

Comment: The threads (1/8”) have probably bunched up at that point and are preventing the bolt from getting to those deeper (presumably good condition) threads. Honestly, I don’t know if *any* way to guarantee that the threads will match other than running from the back ***if*** there is a through-hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up partially grinding down one side of a bolt of the same size/threading. I was able to place it in the hole matching the deeper threads, then driving it all the way in to recut the outer threads. I was then able to get the original bolt back in, hopefully it stays in.[image]

Comment: As an update, it's been almost a year and I haven't had any problems with it.